# How to create Alarm clock application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create iPhone application alarm clock, in this application the user will be able to set the alarm. It is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

An alarm in a UIApplication is known as a local notification.

To create one use the method scheduleLocalNotification:.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification: